# How do I access a parent table in active record other than the obvious way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a schema and model that I'm stuck with.

It has this association:

```
  belongs_to :channel, :primary_key => "channel", :foreign_key => "name"
```

Calling `record.channel` returns `nil`.  I don't know if that means that channel is a reserved word that I just couldn't track down, or if that's what ActiveRecord does when it's not clear if 'channel' should refer to the field or the table.

I'm able to access the field named channel by using the `read_attribute` method.  Is there a similar method that will enable me to access the Channels class through the given record?

Comment: Try reversing 'channel' and 'name'? Also try walking from a channel, via `has_many`, to a record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down this code:

```
belongs_to :channel, :primary_key => "channel", :foreign_key => "name"
```

This means that your model (call it `Foo`) has a foreign key that is the ID of a `Channel`.  So, when you call `Foo.first.channel`, the SQL generated by the above (since you've provided `primary_key` and `foreign_key`) is:

```
SELECT * FROM channels WHERE channels.channel = <Foo.first>.name
```

Generally, in a `belongs_to`, the `primary_key` shouldn't be set - it will be `id` on the associated object.  Also, generally, best practice is to set up the `foreign_key` as `<associated-model-name>_id`.  In this case, on the `Foo` class, it would be `channel_id`.  If it uses this default, neither of those attributes should be necessary.

TL;DR - if `Foo` has `channel_id` as a column, your association would simply be:

```
belongs_to :channel
```

Comment: Not the question I was asking, but I'll give you credit for making me realize that the primary and foreign keys are backwards in the model.

Comment: Not the question no, but I think it'll solve your problem...  The SQL generated by the code you have would not return any rows, thus you'll get back `nil`.

Comment: It does get at the core actually.  It solved the problem, so I'll accept this one, thanks.